# Deserializing a value with ktor than can be either a JsonPrimitive or a JsonArray

Tags: android, json, deserialization, ktor

I am using Ktor for deserialization in my project. I have a json-object that is containing a dynamic value-field, and I am not quite sure how to handle it. Here are some example of the values:

```
"value":["test","rest"]
------------------------
"value":"test"
------------------------
"value":true
```

Any suggestions on how I can best handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can represent it as a list of `String` values but in this case, there is no way to differentiate `true` and `false` values. If you need the result in only one place then you can inline the following code there.

```
val client = HttpClient(OkHttp) {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }
}

val response = client.get("/")
val obj = response.body<JsonObject>()

val values: List<String> = when(val json = obj["value"]) {
    is JsonPrimitive -> {
        when {
            json.isString -> listOf(json.toString()) // JSON string is a list with a single value
            json.booleanOrNull != null -> emptyList() // JSON boolean is an empty list
            else -> error("Expected a string or boolean")
        }
    }

    is JsonArray -> json.map { el -> // JSON array is a list of strings
        if (el is JsonPrimitive && el.isString) {
            el.toString()
        } else {
            error("Expected an array of strings")
        }
    }

    else -> error("Expected an array or primitive value")
}

println(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using Jackson (I believe that it can be done with kotlinx-serialization & gson in a similiar way).

First get ObjectMapper instance to use same settings that you provided to your ktor application (maybe it can be obtained via call instance but i don't know):

```
lateinit var JacksonObjectMapper: ObjectMapper
fun Application.configureJsonSerialization() {
  install(ContentNegotiation) {
  // install Jackson serialization
  jackson {
    // HERE we get ObjectMapper instance to use it later
    JacksonObjectMapper = this
    // ... other jackson config ...
  }
}
```

Then use it:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.treeToValue
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*

fun Application.configureJacksonTestRoute() {
  routing {
      post("/test/json/dynamic-object"){
      val rootObj = call.receive<JsonNode>()
      
      var stringArrayValue: List<String>? = null
      var booleanValue: Boolean? = null
      var stringValue: String? = null
      
      if (rootObj.has("value"))
        rootObj["value"].let {
          // HERE we give a class (List<String>) 
          // to object mapper
          if (it.isArray) stringArrayValue = 
          JacksonObjectMapper.treeToValue<List<String>>(it)
          else if (it.isBoolean) booleanValue = it.asBoolean()
          else if (it.isTextual) stringValue = it.asText()
        }
    
       call.respond("ok")
     }
   }
 }
```